# Association auto-populating with ChoiceDialog

Tags: associations, dialog-window

While trying to use the ChoiceDialog function to populate an association, I have run into an interesting issue...

```
ass=<||>;
ChoiceDialog["which", {"a" -> AssociateTo[ass, "aa" -> "a"], 
  "b" -> AssociateTo[ass, "bb" -> "b"], 
  AssociateTo[ass, "c" -> "cc"]}]
```

After running, and only selecting one option, such as "a" in the choicedialog window, it properly prints out

```
<|aa->a|>
```

But then upon re-calling the association ass, which was not previously populated with anything, now all values have been added to it:

```
ass
```

yields

```
<|"aa" -> "a", "bb" -> "b", "c" -> "cc"|>
```

Why are all values that were placed in the Dialog box being added, and not only the value which I have selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you're using `Rule` (`->`) here to specify the result action for the buttons. `Rule` does not hold its arguments, so all the rules are evaluated during the creation of the window.

If the buttons of your `ChoiceDialog` have side-effects (e.g., they modify a variable), then you should use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) which holds the 2nd argument. Otherwise all side-effects will trigger.

```
ass = <||>;
ChoiceDialog["which",
  {"a" :> AssociateTo[ass, "aa" -> "a"], "b" :> AssociateTo[ass, "bb" -> "b"]}
]
ass
```